# Inserting Date In Cell Upon Checkbox True

Tags: date, google-sheets, checkbox, scripting

I am having issues making this work. I want to insert todays date in colum 4 upon making checkbox true in colum 1. There are multiple rows. I am not seeing the error of my ways. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks,

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var date =  new Date();

  if (e.range.columnStart != 1 || e.value != "TRUE") return;
  ss.getRange(e.range.rowStart,4).setValue(date);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
E.value != "TRUE"
```

Simply use:

```
!e.value
```

And then instead of:

```
ss.getRange(e.range.rowStart,4).setValue(date)
```

You can simply use:

```
e.range.offset(0,3).setValue(date)
```

That allows you to eliminate the need for the ss variable as well.

Comment: Matt, Although it does insert the date as desired I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined. Any idea why and how I can make it run without an error?

Comment: Disregard, I am a noob. Further reading taught me that running this from inside the script editor will produce an error. Once clicking the checkbox cell the script will execute cleanly. Thank you for the help and tips to make my code cleaner!

Comment: I have 2 small issues with the code. 1) If the box is unchecked it also inserts the date and I dont want this becasue if I uncheck it I'd like to be able to have the last date inserted preserved for historical purposes until I decide to check it again in future. 2) I would like to show th date only and in the past I appended  .setNumberFormat to my method but this does not work: e.range.offset(0,3).setValue(date).setNumberFormat("dd-MMM-yy"); any suggestions? Thank you in advnace.

Comment: I decided to use this still: e.value != "TRUE" because it will not overwrite upon uncheck.